# Parsing xml using Java Dom Parser

Tags: java, xml

I am new to Java and XML and i need to fetch some data from an xml file.

Here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<course name="BSc (Hons) Software Engineering" version="5.0" type="FT" lowerbound="2012" upperbound="2014" >
   <year id="1">
      <semester id="1">
         <module>
            <code>HCA1105C</code>
            <name>Computer Architecture</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>PROG1115C</code>
            <name>Object Oriented Software Development I</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MATH1103C</code>
            <name>Decision Mathematics</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>ITE1107C</code>
            <name>Language and Communication Seminar</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MGMT1101C</code>
            <name>Management Seminar</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
      </semester>
      <semester id="2">
         <module>
            <code>PROG1116C</code>
            <name>Object Oriented Software Development II</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>WAT1116C</code>
            <name>Internet Programming I</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MATH1101C</code>
            <name>Analytic Methods for Computing</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>DBT1111C</code>
            <name>Database Design</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
      </semester>
   </year>
   <year id="2">
      <semester id="1">
         <module>
            <code>CAN2112C</code>
            <name>Network Design &amp; Programming</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>WAT2117C</code>
            <name>Internet Programming II</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>OSS2109C</code>
            <name>Operating Systems</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>PROG2117C</code>
            <name>Desktop Application Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
      </semester>
      <semester id="2">
         <module>
            <code>SDT2114C</code>
            <name>Requirements Engineering</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MATH2323C</code>
            <name>Numerical Methods</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MCT2104C</code>
            <name>Mobile Application Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MCT2104C</code>
            <name>Mobile Application Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>WAT2124C</code>
            <name>Web Services</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MGMT2104C</code>
            <name>Research &amp; Development Seminar</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
      </semester>
   </year>
   <year id="3">
      <semester id="1">
         <module>
            <code>SECU3119C</code>
            <name>Secure Software Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MULT3114C</code>
            <name>Game Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>SEM3112C</code>
            <name>Project Management Seminar</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
      </semester>
      <semester id="2">
         <module>
            <code>SDT3104C</code>
            <name>Enterprise Software Development</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>WAT3125C</code>
            <name>Emerging Web Technologies</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>SEM3113C</code>
            <name>Software Quality Management</name>
            <credits>4</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+2</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>MGMT3105C</code>
            <name>Entrepreneurship Seminar</name>
            <credits>3</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk>2+1</hrs_per_wk>
         </module>
         <module>
            <code>PROJ3105C</code>
            <name>Systems Development Project</name>
            <credits>9</credits>
            <hrs_per_wk />
         </module>
      </semester>
   </year>
</course>
```

Lets say that i want to get all modules code that are in semester 1 year 1.

```
HCA1105C
PROG1115C
MATH1103C
ITE1107C
MGMT1101C
```

Here is my code so far

```
try {   
    File inputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/courses/bse.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("year");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(i);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
               //if (Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")) == 1 ) {
                   System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("code").item(0).getTextContent());
               //}
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

I get the following output

```
HCA1105C
CAN2112C
SECU3119C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking child nodes and dive into for modules will give your expected result as below;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File inputFile = new File("Snippet.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("year");
            for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(i);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    if (Integer.parseInt(eElement.getAttribute("id")) == 1) { // Found year 1
                        NodeList semeterList = nNode.getChildNodes();
                        for (int j = 0; j < semeterList.getLength(); j++) {
                            nNode = semeterList.item(j);
                            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                Element semesterNode = (Element) nNode;
                                if (Integer.parseInt(semesterNode.getAttribute("id")) == 1) { //Found semester 1
                                    NodeList moduleList = semesterNode.getChildNodes();
                                    for (int k = 0; k < moduleList.getLength(); k++) {
                                        nNode = moduleList.item(k);
                                        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                            Element modeluNode = (Element) nNode;
                                            System.out.println(modeluNode.getElementsByTagName("code").item(0).getTextContent());
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is reading 1st module of every year. This is because, the node list will have 3 nodes (year=1, year=2, year=3) for the criteria you have specified.

If you want to read all modules of year 1, then you need to recurse in to the sub-section of the document with year="1". Then you will get nodelist of semesters. You need to further recurse in to children of semester=1.

You may try using query with xpath, where you can get the modules of year=1 and semester=1 directly.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

*EDITED* with modified code using XPath:

```
try {   
    File inputFile = new File("courses.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        String expression = "/course/year[@id=1]/semester[@id=1]/module/code";
        NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(expression);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodeList.item(i).getTextContent()); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Comment: A slight modification would be to fetch the module nodes and then get the code from there. Depending on if you need any of the extra information or not. But this should be the preferred answer though.

Answer (score 0):

We can fetch all the codes through DOM, by using following code:

```
try {   
        File inputFile = new File("src/resources/res.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("module");
        for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
             Node nNode = nList.item(i);
             if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                 Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                 System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("code").item(0).getTextContent());
             }
        }
     } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Fatal Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(1);
      }
```

We can also, fetch code by looping each year --> semester --> module, then fetch the attribute code. Above code gives following results:

HCA1105C
PROG1115C
MATH1103C
ITE1107C
MGMT1101C
PROG1116C
WAT1116C
MATH1101C
DBT1111C
CAN2112C
WAT2117C
OSS2109C
PROG2117C
SDT2114C
MATH2323C
MCT2104C
MCT2104C
WAT2124C
MGMT2104C
SECU3119C
MULT3114C
SEM3112C
SDT3104C
WAT3125C
SEM3113C
MGMT3105C
PROJ3105C